# "Lost connection to test manager service" when running unit tests in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

Almost every time I run unit tests inside the iOS simulator from Xcode a random test fails with "Lost connection to test manager service". What does this mean? Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: We see this a lot with asynchronous testing. XCTestExpectation's and Quick/Nimble toEventually and waitUntil are the worst offenders. Unfortunately I have no solution, but I just thought I'd provide some more detail. I believe this is an Xcode 7 issue, as there are a few questions popping up recently regarding this issue

Comment: @MaxClarke The thing is, those tests that are failing are not asynchronous at all, actually I have just a couple of tests that use expectations but they rarely (if ever) fail.

Comment: I seem to be getting this all the time — two integrations in a row have had this problem in 98/105 tests. (I'm using iPad Air 2 simulator, if that matters.) This is all local testing, nothing asynch. Xcode 7.3.1.

Answer (score -1):

I've ran into this problem recently. This happened when I ran asynchronous tests and I wanted to verify if the api calls were made with correct endpoints and parameters using OCMock.

Turns out it was pretty simple, one of my parameter values was set to string while it is supposed to be an int. Please make sure that you have everything properly set up for the test.